# Having trouble trying to install Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am having trouble trying to install numpy this is the following error i get while install numpy i have tried installing it from pip but that gives diffrent error.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install J:\python\pandas-0.19.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Processing j:\python\pandas-0.19.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.19.2)
Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas==0.19.2)
  Using cached numpy-1.11.3.zip
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas==0.19.2)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\VIRALC~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().rep
lace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-1dof7h7v-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Running from numpy source directory.

```
Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install numpy`   (last Numpy release on PyPi)


blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1630: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1639: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1642: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\python\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\python\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\python\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\python\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1532: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1543: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1546: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6\numpy
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visu
```

alstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pi
p-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.clo
se();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-1dof7h7v-record\in
stall-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\VIRALC~1\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\pip-build-4rq6hgfg\numpy\

Comment: Which python verison are you using ? Which numpy version do you have?  Have you tried running `pip install pandas` ? or `pip install numpy` ?